# Не удается вытащить ссылку из респонса, с помощью .split()

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

На проекте последнее письмо по указанному адресу можно вызвать реквестом. Иного способа пока нет.
Они приходят в ответе как HTML код самого письма и вытащить ссылку как href не представляется не возможным, во флэт тексте ее не определяет.

Я пытаюсь использовать .split(regexp), чтобы выделить ссылку подтверждения аккаунта, но в логах получаю не разделенный текст.

Подскажите, что в итоге идет не так.

Использую следующий код:

```
 cy.request({
        method: 'GET',
        url: *Здесь ссылка на получение письма*
    }).then(($response) => {
        var encodedResponse = JSON.parse($response.body)
        var re = /(?<=f=")([\s\S]+?)(?=")/g
        var acceptAccountLink = $response.body.split(re)

        cy.log('Subject is '+encodedResponse.subject)
        expect(encodedResponse.subject).to.equal('Добро пожаловать в IYNO!')

        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/email/getsignupuser.json', {encodedResponse})
    
        cy.log(acceptAccountLink)

        cy.log('Using accept link on the board')
        cy.visit(acceptAccountLink, {timeout:10000})

    })
```

Comment: Наверное, вам нужно `var acceptAccountLink = $response.body.match(re)?.[0]`

Comment: Это помогло! Огромное спасибо.
Повтыкаю еще гайдлайны, чтобы понять как работает .match().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
 let response = await fetch('Здесь ссылка на получение письма');
 let json = await response.json();
 let re = /(?<=f=")([\s\S]+?)(?=")/g;
 console.log(json.body.match(re))
```